# Concatenate H.264 raw but basic streams without reencoding or quality loss

Tags: h.264, concatenation, lossless

How does one go about concatenating several H.264 raw streams into one without reencoding or quality loss?

The streams lacked any advanced features and represented contuous recording. There is no random seek/random access feature, either.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following way, when trying to concatenate videostreams from the dashcam. Note: the streams had no random seek/random access

On Windows, perform the following,

```
copy /b file1.264 + file2.264 + file3.264 result.264
```

The command would byte-merge the raw streams, which works out well. If no random seek/random access feature existed, then it won't appear; but upon the uploading to YouTube, the random seek/random access feature was re-added.

Inspired by [this source](https://superuser.com/a/1031182)

Comment: YT encodes, so the random seek wasn't "added" *per se*. The uploaded video was encoded into a new file with the feature. But that the file successfully uploads to YT is great!